# Why we needed two different approach in ATG -pull based(droplet) and push based(formhandlers)?

Tags: atg

I know the question is about solving the problem probably by different approach but let me specify in details what I want to ask and how much I understand about it.

We have two mvc approach used in ATG(or many other framework) pull based and push based.
As I understand it formhandlers and droplet both are playing the part of controller in different need, repositories are our model and jsps are providing views..
And if i am right till this point then what purpose the servlet chain is solving?How it fits into this picture of MVC?

Please If possible explain with the help of flow diagram from request to response (end to end).

Thanks a lot in advance to experts.
Please help.I could not find this kind of explanation anywhere.

Comment: Suggest you look at the DAF pipeline in the ATG help. This does the request and response handling at the bare bones level.  The DAF Pipelines take a raw http request/response and convert to DynamoHttpServletRequest/Response. The servlet pipeline takes care of things like session management, security, etc.  There is limited documentation on what each of the servlets do but in general the names are pretty self explanatory.  Also remember that ATG was originally built to run on  ATG's own Dynamo server and used the DAS pipeline which did lot more than the DAF pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to remember with ATG is that it is an old platform. So when trying to understand the different mechanisms through an MVC lens, remember that nothing was designed with MVC in mind-the platform predates widespread knowledge and acceptance of the MVC pattern in web development.

Droplets are a generalized mechanism for invoking Java code from a JSP (and previously, JHTML) template. The closest analogue in J2EE-land would be tag libraries. So you can use them to accomplish many different tasks. You can also use them as a poor man's MVC controller. This is done by coding a custom droplet class dedicated to handling the business logic of your page, and setting relevant page state as request parameters. Then you invoke the droplet as the first step in your JSP page. This is not very different from J2EE model 2 with the odd quirk that first your compiled JSP begins executing, then invokes your "controller" code and then resumes with processing the "view."

Form handlers, as the name indicates, are designed for processing form submissions. These are executed by a link in the servlet pipeline (DAFDropletEventServlet), before the page which was posted to begins rendering. Typical usage with form handlers is that they will send a redirect after executing, and cancel rendering of the page, which will abort any further processing by the servlet pipeline. Form handlers are the closest thing to a "controller" ATG provides. But they are awful for handling GET requests and result in some very unfortunate URLs when used for this purpose.

Why did they create two different mechanisms? Why have they not subsequently introduced an updated MVC model as part of the platform? These questions I cannot answer.

Answer (score 0):

ATG, at the page rendering level, is not MVC. Don't look at it as MVC. ATG, at its core, is an extension of the basic Servlets API.

Forms and form-processing, with the `successUrl` and `errorUrl` is kind-of MVC. Droplets certainly are not.

It is perfectly acceptable in an ATG application to be fetching data as the page is rendering (i.e. Droplets)